# Javascript: access server side variable client side using variable

Tags: javascript, client-side, server-side, var

I am attempting to:

1. Use JQuery to 'loop' through all elements on a page that belong to the same CSS class ("boilerplate")
2. Check the current value of each against it's server side assigned value (property: StaticPrefill)
3. Apply a special css class ("editedbackcolor") if the two values do not match (ie I'm trying to flag when someone has edited the prefilled text on textboxes)

**CSS I am using:**

.boilerplate = assign to all text boxes I'm trying to check on the form

.editedbackcolor = different shade I want to assign to textboxes where current value does NOT equal server side StaticPrefill value.

**jQuery code I have so far is:**

jQuery(document).ready(function () {

```
        // select each element with class boilerplate and run a function against it
        jQuery('.boilerplate input').each(function () {              
            var target1 = jQuery(this).attr("id");
            matchcheck(target1);
        });
    });
```

and I'm working on the "matchcheck) function which is where I am having a problem. I'm trying to pull back the server side "StaticPrefill" property value that I can use as a comparison. I've successfully queried this by hardcoding a control name, like:

```
function matchcheck(){         
                var TSP1 = '<%= TextBox1.StaticPrefill %>';
                // If current textbox value does NOT equal it's static prefill value
                if (document.getElementById("Textbox1_textbox1").value != TSP1) {
                alert("TB1 has differnt value than static prefill");
                // change background color to flag it
                jQuery("#Textbox1_textbox1").addClass("EditedBackColor");                   
                }
            }
```

That works fine, but I don't want to use a variable to loop through all elements instead of the hardcoded "TextBox1" in the first line of the function. I've tried different syntaxes in an attempt to put a variable between the '<%= ' and '%>' tags but the page won't compile when I try this.

Is this possible w/o using code behind of some sort? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

An easier approach, if I understand your question, is to bind to the [change event](http://api.jquery.com/change/) in jQuery.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.boilerplate input').change(function() {
       if(jQuery(this).val() !== jQuery(this).attr("prefill")) {
        jQuery(this)removeClass('boilerplate').addClass("EditedBackColor");
       }
    });
});
```

You will also need to add an attribute called "prefill" to your input elements.  You can do that server side or client side.  It should look something like this:

```
<input class="boilerplate" id="input1" type="text" prefill="123" value="123"/>
```

The caveat here is that if they change it back to the original value, it will still show as changed.  I'm not sure if that works for you in your scenario.  They did change it per se.  You would have to save off the original value as an attribute if it did not exist.  The other option is to send down a model, maybe a json object, and compare to that model based on index.

Comment: My issue isn't applying the CSS class, it's doing the check of each element's value on the form against it's individual server side "StaticPrefill" property value. I need to compare these to decide IF i want to do the CSS change..